# In-App Purchase Error , Always myProduct is 0

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

My VC like this:

```
var coins = 50 // coins
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
        //print("enabled, loading")
        let productID: NSSet = NSSet(objects: "com.tahabuyruk.taha.coinsal", "com.tahabuyruk.taha.reklam") // my products Id
        let request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    } else {
        print("please enable IAPS")
    }
}

//I have 2 products on itunesconnect

@IBAction func btnRemoveAds(_ sender: Any) {
    print("rem ads")
    for product in list {
        let prodID = product.productIdentifier
        if(prodID == "com.tahabuyruk.taha.reklam") { 
            // ad product id
            p = product
            buyProduct()
        }
    }
}

// my bundle id is com.tahabuyruk.taha 
// my product id is com.tahabuyruk.taha.coins 

@IBAction func satinAl(_ sender: Any) { // addCoin Button
    for product in list {
        let prodID = product.productIdentifier
        if(prodID == "com.tahabuyruk.taha.coinsal") {
            p = product
            buyProduct()
        }
    }
}

func buyProduct() {
    print("buy " + p.productIdentifier)
    let pay = SKPayment(product: p)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(pay as SKPayment)
}

func removeAds() {
    lblAd.removeFromSuperview()
}

func addCoins() {
    coins += 50
    lblCoinAmount.text = "\(coins)"
}

var list = [SKProduct]()
var p = SKProduct()

func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    print("product request")
    let myProduct = response.products // myProduct is always be 0 . I don't know why .
    for product in myProduct {
        print("product added")
        print(product.productIdentifier)
        print(product.localizedTitle)
        print(product.localizedDescription)
        print(product.price)
        list.append(product)
    }
}

func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
    print("transactions restored")
    for transaction in queue.transactions {
        let t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction
        let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String

        switch prodID {
        case "com.tahabuyruk.taha.reklam":// ad product id
            print("remove ads")
            removeAds()
        case "com.tahabuyruk.taha.coinsal":
            print("add coins to account")
            addCoins()
        default:
            print("IAP not found")
        }
    }
}

func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    print("add payment")

    for transaction: AnyObject in transactions {
        let trans = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction
        print(trans.error)

        switch trans.transactionState {
        case .purchased:
            print("buy ok")
            print(p.productIdentifier)

            let prodID = p.productIdentifier
            switch prodID {
            case "com.tahabuyruk.taha.reklam":// ad product id
                print("remove ads")
                removeAds()
            case "com.tahabuyruk.taha.coinsal":
                print("add coins to account")
                addCoins()
            default:
                print("IAP not found")
            }
            queue.finishTransaction(trans)
        case .failed:
            print("buy error")
            queue.finishTransaction(trans)
            break
        default:
            print("Default")
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Always myProduct is 0.
What's wrong with this code?
I want to know why always be 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I handle this problem , look for Agreements , Tax and Banking and check that your banking, contact and tax information has been filled up